# usage of "currently"

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is difference between these two sentences :

**sentence 1** : He has currently been a teacher

**sentence 2** : He is currently a teacher

Answer (score -1):

> He is currently a teacher./ He is currently working as a teacher in a primary school.

This sentence is grammatically correct. *Currently* being an adverb modifies the verb "is". This sentence indicates that the boy is a teacher and is continuing with that profession. The sentence represents the whole situation to be in present tense (*or present continuous tense*).

> He has currently been a teacher./ He has currently been working as a teacher in a primary school.

This statement is wrong. ***Currently*** refers to only the present time. Hence cannot be used in past tense nor the present perfect tense, since it starts in the past and continues in the present. Not acceptable.

An alternative for the second statement will be:

> He has been a teacher for a while now.

As for your question, the usage of *"currently"* is proper only in the first sentence, not the second one.

Comment: Currently refers _only_ to the present, so you cannot say "he has been currently [something].

Comment: Yeah the meaning of currently states that. So you mean, it is only used in simple present tense?

Comment: That's what it says in the dictionary. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: I don't disagree with the meaning. I did not create that. Thanks. I will edit it.

Comment: I am currently living in Bristol. I have been living here for some years.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes I understand. I have edited my answer. I feel sorry for misguiding the OP. Sorry. And thank you so much.